# Looking for information on a programming language called WhatDoesItDo

Tags: programming, 6800

I am looking for information on a training language called "WhatDoesItDo". It was used in 1978 at Austin Community College on a Motorola 6800 CPU.

If anyone has any information, I would appreciate it very, very much.

Comment: Do you have any reference at all about that language?

Comment: For what it's worth, I've implemented most of WATDUZITDO's parent, [PILOT, in PowerShell](https://github.com/FreeTrav/psPILOT).

Answer (score 21):

> I am looking for information on a training language called "WhatDoesItDo".

It was called WADUZITDO

Well, for training purposes, you might check out the online-version at [Waduzitdo.org](http://waduzitdo.org/). It hosts a faithful (*1) port to JavaScript (*2), even including a few quirks of the original 6800 version. It offers as well an online reference of all legal instructions.

> It was used in 1978 at Austin Community College on a Motorola 6800 CPU.

Serious? Now that's a cool fact to know. Do you have any reference?

> If anyone has any information,

As usual, the [Esolang-Wiki](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Main_Page) got [some information](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Waduzitdo), including a link to the Archive.org copy for the original [Byte article](https://archive.org/details/byte-magazine-1978-09/page/n167/mode/2up) of September 1978 (p.166), showing the 6800 Assembly source.

---

*1 - Sans the editor. A text box is simply more convenient today.

*2 - The port was made on Christmas 2005 and contains some 'tricks' to ensure workings on different Browsers (anyone remember the Browser Wars? The early 2000s were a horror for web applications) and relies on certain workings for text output which seem no longer true (or maybe simply optimized away by modern JS engines).

Answer (score 13):

A CP/M implementation can be found in the SIG/M archives, [volume 28](http://www.classiccmp.org/cpmarchives/cpm/mirrors/oak.oakland.edu/pub/sigm/vol028/) as `waduzit.com`, `waduzit.doc` and `waduzit.pas`.

From the Pascal source:

```
{
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ PROGRAM TITLE:        What Does It Do?                +
+                                                       +
+ WRITTEN BY:           Larry Kheriaty, Computer Center +
+                       Western Washington Univ.        +
+                       Bellingham, Wa. 98225           +
+                       BYTE MAG, Sept 1978             +
+                                                       +
+ SUMMARY:                                              +
+ A minimal PILOT interpreter.  A sample of what can be +
+ done with the high level language Pascal. Commands    +
+ will be found in the file WADUZIT.DOC.                +
```